# Play a byteArray flv through FLVPlayback component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, encryption, loader

Is there any way of playing a byteArray through a FLVPlayback component?

I want to load an Encrypted video, decrypt it and play it.
I can do the loading and decrypting part but i don't know how to play it through a FLVPlayback component. With seeking functions and play stop buttons.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to load and play FLV video in ByteArray form, but I don't know if it's possible to couple this with the seek, play and pause functionality through an FLVPlayback component itself.

In my example I've added pause/unpause functionality, but seeking is difficult since the workaround treats this ByteArray as an RTMP stream from a server, as opposed to a progressively loaded video.

This is a document class for an FLA with an FLVPlayback component on the stage (with instance name `flvPlayback`), and it just embeds a local FLV as ByteArray, which is referenced at the top:

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.net.NetStreamAppendBytesAction;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import fl.video.FLVPlayback;

    public class VideoFromByteArray extends Sprite {

        [Embed(source="your_video.flv", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private var TestVideo:Class;

        public var flvPlayback:FLVPlayback; //Instantiated on stage in FLA//
        private var _nc:NetConnection;
        private var _ns:NetStream;
        private var _ba:ByteArray;

        public function VideoFromByteArray() {
            ui_init();
        }

        private function ui_init():void {
            _nc = new NetConnection();
            _nc.connect(null);

            _ns = new NetStream(_nc);
            _ns.client = { };
            _ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ns_netStatus);
            flvPlayback.getVideoPlayer(0).attachNetStream(_ns);

            _ba = new TestVideo();
            _ns.play(null);
            _ns.appendBytes(_ba);
            _ns.send("|RtmpSampleAccess", true, true);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stage_click);
        }

        private function stage_click(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            _ns.togglePause();
        }

        private function ns_netStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
            var code:String = event.info.code;
            switch(code) {
                case "NetStream.Buffer.Empty":
                    _ns.seek(0);
                    break;
                case "NetStream.Seek.Notify":
                    if (event.info.seekPoint == 0) ns_seekToBeginning();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function ns_seekToBeginning():void {
            _ns.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);
            _ns.appendBytes(_ba);
            _ns.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.END_SEQUENCE);
        }

    }
}
```