# Trigger HTML5 track element cue manually

Tags: flash, html5-video

Is there a way to use the html5 track element cues without an html5 video element or audio element, or perhaps without loading a video or audio into one of those? I have an html5 video player with a flash fallback, and I'd love to use the track apis with the flash player component when it is needed. Any way to trick a text track into thinking the time has changed on an empty video element or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, because when you don't have a video, the readyState is `0`, `HAVE_NOTHING`, so everything else just seems to be ignored.

As a workaround, you can use `ffmpeg` to generate a blank video and start from there:

```
ffmpeg -t 30 -s 1x1 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 25 -i /dev/zero spacer.mp4
```

A clip 30 seconds short got ~21kb and another, with 5 minutes, ~103kb.

You could also embed the video using a base64 encoded string, but you'll probably have problems with that on Flash. You'd need to decode the base64 data to ByteArray, which doesn't play nice with videos. If you have the Flash video player's source, it should be easier to implement a workaround (for the text tracks) there and another one for the HTML.

**Sources**:

- [Generating blank videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453082/how-to-generate-a-2hour-long-blank-video)
- [Base64 Encoded Video](http://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/video.php)
- [Open question, about playing video from ByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822365/play-a-bytearray-flv-through-flvplayback-component)
- [Rendering video from ByteArray to BitmapData, as a workaround](http://gamespoweredby.com/blog/2014/11/netstream-playnull-bitmapdata-workaround/)